# Remove JQuery hover event when hovering over children

Tags: jquery, hover, tooltip

I am building a tooltip, where if you hover over a marker, the tooltip appears.

HTML:

```
<div class="trigger" data-loc="locationE" id="locationE">
    <div class="tooltip">
        <h2>Here is a title</h2>
        <p>Here is some Compy About this location</p>
        <h3>215.237.9932</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tooltip").each(function() {
        toolHeight = $(this).outerHeight();
        toolHeightPlus = $(this).outerHeight() + 20;
        $(this).css({
            "top": -+toolHeight
        });
    });
    $(".trigger").hover(function() {
        $("#" + $(this).data("loc") + " .tooltip").stop().animate({
            "opacity": "1",
            "top": -+toolHeightPlus
        });
    }, function() {
        $("#" + $(this).data("loc") + " .tooltip").stop().animate({
            "opacity": "0",
            "top": -+toolHeight
        });
    });
});
```

The reason I am using the data attribute does not need to be mentioned here, as it's for another part of the application. The problem I am having is that the user triggers the tooltip animation when they hover over where the tooltip is positioned, even though the opacity is at 0. I want the toolip to trigger ONLY when the user hovers over the `.trigger` not the `.tooltip` that has zero opacity. How would I accomplish this?

Comment: `$('element').unbind('hover');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to set your tooltip css display to "none" while it is hidden and set to "block" when it is to be shown. This would prevent the .tooltip html element from occupying any space when it is not supposed to be visible.

Comment: To me, this solution works best, combining opacity and display to achieve the desired result.Thanks!

Comment: @JCHASE11 - This won't work.  When you make `.tooltip` `display:none`, then `.trigger` will have no size and you will not be able to hover it unless you add other content or fix it's size with CSS.

Comment: oh it works just great, see my jquery:  $(".trigger").hover(function(){

      $("#" + $(this).data("loc") + " .tooltip").stop().css({"display" : "block"}).animate({"opacity" : "1", "top" : - + toolHeightPlus});
   }, function(){
      $("#" + $(this).data("loc") + " .tooltip").stop().animate({ opacity : 0, top : - + toolHeight}, 500, function(){
       $(this).css({"display" : "none"});
      });
   });

Answer (score 0):

Move the tool tip markup out of the trigger.  Since the trigger div is wrapping the tooltip, it's actually popping up the tooltip. If you intent was to *only* do this with hovering over the trigger, then make them separate elements.

Comment: Sure, I can do that, but that tampers with the rest of my application...I can do that if there is no solution, while keeping them inside the trigger. Any way to keep them inside?

Answer (score 0):

Your request looks problematic with your HTML because there is no space in your HTML that is only `.trigger`, so it appears to me like your request can never work unless you add more content to the `.trigger` element that is not the `.tooltip` element.

If you did add more space to the `.trigger` element, then I you can look at the [target of the event](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) and see if it has the right class like this before acting:

```
$(".trigger").hover(function(e) {
    if (!$(e.target).hasClass(".trigger")) return;
    $("#" + $(this).data("loc") + " .tooltip").stop().animate({
        "opacity": "1",
        "top": -+toolHeightPlus
    });
}, function(e) {
    $("#" + $(this).data("loc") + " .tooltip").stop().animate({
        "opacity": "0",
        "top": -+toolHeight
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for this, good solution, but I dont want to add any additional elements.

Comment: @JCHASE11 - Do you understand that your HTML has NO space on the screen that is only `.trigger` and not `.tooltip` so there is no solution to your question without changing your HTML.